# How to setup JupyterHub with Django?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, jupyterhub

I'm trying to build a Django web application that will have Jupyter notebook through the JupyterHub server embedded within the app, where users could login via the app and can access the notebook once they are in. I'm trying to use OAuth2 where JupyterHub verifies the authenticated users that Django provides.

I am using `django-oauth-toolkit` for the authentication service and linking it using `DjangoOAuthentication`.

I have the `DjangoOAuthenticator.oauth_callback_url` linked to 'http://localhost:8081/hub/oauth_callback'

I have the Redirect URIs (on Django) linked to 'http://localhost:8081/hub/oauth_callback'

I get:

> **404 : Not Found** Jupyter has lots of moons, but this is not one...

```
[I 2019-03-18 16:28:54.195 JupyterHub oauth2:82] OAuth redirect: 'http://localhost:8081/hub/oauth_callback'
[I 2019-03-18 16:28:54.198 JupyterHub log:158] 302 GET /hub/oauth_login?next= -> localhost/oauth2/authorize?client_id=zkn2mFYhhNcs3bDTnwIWK0mDuLBdLAe2eMENE5Xa&response_type=code&state=[secret]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fhub%2Foauth_callback (@127.0.0.1) 3.94ms
[W 2019-03-18 16:28:54.230 JupyterHub log:158] 404 GET /hub/localhost/oauth2/authorize?client_id=zkn2mFYhhNcs3bDTnwIWK0mDuLBdLAe2eMENE5Xa&response_type=code&state=[secret]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fhub%2Foauth_callback (@127.0.0.1) 17.81ms
```

The URL it goes to:

```
http://localhost:8081/hub/localhost/oauth2/authorize?client_id=zkn2mFYhhNcs3bDTnwIWK0mDuLBdLAe2eMENE5Xa&response_type=code&state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICJlZTA0MmRiYmU4YTY0ZmIxYTk0ODU0MjFiMzhhMWYwOCIsICJuZXh0X3VybCI6ICIifQ%3D%3D&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fhub%2Foauth_callback
```

I believe I have either the `oauth_callback_url` or the `redirect_uri` on Django  wrong.

Note: *My question is not a duplicate of [Use Django OAuth2 provider with JupyterHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175325/use-django-oauth2-provider-with-jupyterhub). We have different errors.*

Comment: I assume that you're using Jupyterhub's [oauthenticator](https://github.com/jupyterhub/oauthenticator). This implements an *OAuth client*. And you should set the URL of your *OAuth service provider* to OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL, which is the OAuth portal of your Django server.

Comment: Please refer to a config example [here](https://github.com/scnerd/jupyterhub_django_oauth2/blob/6483fa07ce9a1b98ce4ff21389dd3cb91ab03815/docker-compose.yml#L22).

Comment: @user11154441 were you able to find a  solution for the question. I'm trying to do the same and stuck for some time now